# Why components involved in request response flow should not consume messages on a kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, microservices

As part of design decision at my client site, the components(microservice) involved in http request-response flow are allowed to produce messsages on a kafka topic, **but not allowed** to consume messages from kafka topic.

Such components(microservice) **can** read & write database,  **can** talk to other components, **can** produce messages on a topic, **but cannot** consume messages from a kafka topic.

Instead ,the design suggest to write separate utilities that consume messages from kafka topics and store in database. Components(microservice) involved in request-response flow, will read that information from database.

What are the design flaws, if such components(microservice) consume kafka topics? Why the design is suggesting to write separate utilities to consume kafka topic and store in database, so that components can read those information from database.

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes, request handling machines are clustered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Topics are divided into partitions, and for each consumer group, the partitions are distributed among the various consumers in that group. Each consumer is responsible for consuming the messages in the partitions is gets assigned.

Presumably, your request handling machines are clustered and load balanced.  There are two ways you might have those machines subscribe to Kafka topics, and both of those ways are broken:

1. You could put your request handling machines in different consumer groups.  In this case, each one will have to consume *all of the messages*.  That is probably not what you want, which is typically to have each consumer pull from the queue and have each message processed only once.  Also, the consumers will be out of sync and will process the messages ad different rates.
2. You could put your request handling machines in the same consumer groups.  In this case, each one will only have access to the partitions that it is assigned. Every machine will see *different message streams*.  This, of course, is also not what you want.  Clients would get different results depending on which machine the load balancer directed them to.

If you want all of your request handling machines to pull from the same queue of messages across the whole topic, then they need to communicate with a single consumer that is assigned all the partitions.

Comment: Why request handling machines cannot be in different consumer groups? Aah... because in our case each request handling machine has multiple goroutines(GoLang thread accepting http requests)

Comment: Is request handling machine safe to produce messages for a kafka topic?